# Auto generating sub pages

Tags: php, html, mysql

- I am trying to do so when you press an username on the page, it takes
  you to the usernames profile page.
- I want the link to the profile page to be like
  www.page.com/users/(name).
- Currently I have it so it open www.page.com/users.php?user=(name) and
  it works fine, but I would like it if I could make it like what I
  want it, you get me?

My current link to the users page is

```
$pageFeedOutput .= '<a name="name" value="' .$Username .'" href="users.php?user=' .$Username .'">' .$Username .'</a></p>';
```

The users.php looks like this

```
<?php
$user = '';
$outputUser = '';
$user = $_GET['user'] or die($outputUser = 'No user');
$outputUser = $user;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3><?php print('USER: ' .$outputUser); ?><h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

I got a database too and I'm using that for keeping info on the users.
Any help appreciated. Ask for more info if you need it, but I think I got it all now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a ".htaccess" file on the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteRule ^.*/([a-z_]+\.php)/(.*)$ $1/$2 [L]
```

The rule may have to be changed.

Comment: This put me on the right tracks, and I did what I wanted to do editing the .htaccess file. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This also comes for free if you use any decent framework such as Zend or Symphony.